# How to change the background for Google Chrome "new tab"?

Tags: image, google-chrome, background, tabs

(I'm kinda new to this programming in JS)
So... My problem is that I had successfully changed my Google Chrome "new tab" background image, however, now I want to change it back via the same means, such as replacing background-image in elements:

```
body, #viewport {

background-image: 
url("http://lh5.ggpht.com/NbIEDIi5H6inUPkNM7QbCHWHzslg1mIZoy4jrWTG1cd_nokTf0diak_Yz5rsQ3wFZjgfc31Lm-QvgqV5b9R-=s1440") !important;

background-repeat: no-repeat !important;

background-position: center !important;

background-size: cover !important;

}
```

I tried to "overwrite" it by copy and pasting a new link but it doesn't seem to save...
So does anyone have a solution to this?